# Dynamic SQL in a Common Table Expression in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to return a dynamic `SQL` using a `CTE (Common Table Expression)` in `TSQL`, my attempt below doesn't work:

> NOTE: the query below uses a linked server, but my question is related
>   to any SQL even not using the openquery command.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(DATABASE1, ''SELECT * FROM tblRequisitions'')'

;WITH requisitions AS
(
   EXEC (@sql)
)
SELECT * from requisitions
```

How can I make this dynamic SQL to load into my `CTE`?

Comment: I don't think you can. You're asking SQL to select something and execute something at the same time. Maybe execute your query into a temp table,then select from the temp table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't incorporate dynamic sql into regular sql like that. What you can do is create a temp table, insert the dynamic output into the temp table and then reference the temp table in the CTE. Something along these lines...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp;

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    -- ColumnName DataType
    );
INSERT #temp (ColumnName)
EXEC (@sql);

WITH
    cte_requisitions AS (
        SELECT 
            *
        FROM 
            #temp t
        )
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    cte_requisitions r;
```

Comment: It looks a good solution, I did it, but when I run the query it displays "Command(s) completed successfully" but it doesn't return anything :/. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the temp table definition exactly match the output of the dynamic sql?

Comment: oww, I found the issue, was something else, so sorry, and thanks for your amazing help, I will set your answer as correct.

Comment: Good deal, I'm glad you got it squared away and working. Glad I could be of assistance. :)